# OutOfMemoryError while Logistic regression in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark

I have successfully installed Apache Spark, Hadoop over Ubuntu 12.04 (Single standalone mode) for Logistic regression. Also tested with small csv dataset but it doesnt work over large dataset having 269369 rows.

```
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init()
iterations <- as.integer(11)
D <- 540

readPartition <- function(part){
part = strsplit(part, ",", fixed = T)
list(matrix(as.numeric(unlist(part)), ncol = length(part[[1]])))
}
w <- runif(n=D, min = -1, max = 1)

cat("Initial w: ", w, "\n")

# Compute logistic regression gradient for a matrix of data points
gradient <- function(partition) {
  partition = partition[[1]]
  Y <- partition[, 1] # point labels (first column of input file)

  X <- partition[, -1] # point coordinates
  # For each point (x, y), compute gradient function
  #print(w)
  dot <- X %*% w      
  logit <- 1 / (1 + exp(-Y * dot))
  grad <- t(X) %*% ((logit - 1) * Y)
  list(grad)
}


for (i in 1:iterations) {
  cat("On iteration ", i, "\n")
  w <- w - reduce(lapplyPartition(points, gradient), "+")
}

> points <- cache(lapplyPartition(textFile(sc, "hdfs://localhost:54310/henry/cdata_mr.csv"), readPartition))
```

The error message I got:

```
14/10/07 01:47:16 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/10/07 01:47:28 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_23_0 in memory! Free memory is 235841615 bytes.
14/10/07 01:47:42 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_23_1 in memory! Free memory is 236015334 bytes.
14/10/07 01:47:55 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_23_2 in memory! Free memory is 236015334 bytes.
14/10/07 01:48:10 WARN CacheManager: Not enough space to cache partition rdd_23_3 in memory! Free memory is 236015334 bytes.
14/10/07 01:48:29 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 17)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD$$anon$2.read(RRDD.scala:144)
    at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD$$anon$2.<init>(RRDD.scala:156)
    at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:227)
    at edu.berkeley.cs.amplab.sparkr.RRDD.compute(RRDD.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
14/10/07 01:48:29 ERROR ExecutorUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
```

Dimension of data (sample) :

```
data <- read.csv("/home/Henry/data.csv")

dim(data)

[1] 269369 541
```

I have also tried hosting the same csv file over local file system as well as on HDFS. I think it will need more Hadoop datanotes to store large datasets?. If it is then how can I set up Spark Hadoop cluster to get rid of this. (or I am doing something wrong)

Tip: I think increasing Java and Spark heap space will help me to run this. I tried a lot for doing it but not succeeded. Can any one know what is the way to increase heap space for both.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try setting `spark.executor.memory` to a larger value as documented [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)? As a back-of-the-envelope calculation, assuming each entry in your dataset takes 4 bytes, the whole file in memory would cost `269369 * 541 * 4 bytes ~= 560MB`, which is over the default `512m` value for that parameter.

As an example, try something like (assuming each worker node in your cluster has more than 1GB memory available):

```
sc <- sparkR.init("local[2]", "SparkR", "/home/spark",
                  list(spark.executor.memory="1g"))
```